# Find what apex a cronjob Triggers

Tags: apex, soql, schedulebatch, cron

**Scenario:**

Documentation on my org has a gap regarding a scheduled batch apex. This batch code updates a related list on the lead object. This List and process is call ‘nearby references’ and ‘find nearby references’ respectively.

I have found what class it is firing by correlating run times between a cronjob and AsyncApexJob records.
Which I did using SOQL queries:

```
SELECT CronExpression, EndTime, CronJobDetailId, CronJobDetail.Name, NextFireTime FROM CronTrigger WHERE CronJobDetail.JobType = '7' AND CronJobDetail.name = 'Weekly Nearby References'
```

The WHERE filters came second once I found the cronjobdetail named 'Weekly Nearby References'

I used the Cron Expression from this to search asyncapexjobs for a record that matched that time.

```
SELECT id, Startime, ApexClassID, CompletedDate, ExtendedStatus, JobType, MethodName, Status FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE CompletedDate > 2019-01-06T00:00:00.000+0000 AND CompletedDate < 2019-01-07T00:00:00.000+0000 AND apexClassId = '01pC000000XXXXXX' and jobtype != 'BatchApexWorker'
```

Again WHERE filters of classid and jobtype came later as I zeroed in. Allowing me to see “findNearbyReferences” class was the one firing at that time.

**Problem**

I believe it was scheduled via system.schedule()

I need to find the class that was called to schedule this batch.  But I can’t seem to find what scheduled the cron job or connects it to the asyncapexjob record.

**Essentially; how Do I find what apex a cronjob Triggers?**

Comment: Hi Ryan, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. Your title is essentially backwards from what you seem to be trying to find out. Please note that the format here is ***question*** and ***answer***. But you do not actually *ask* anything above. Please try to structure your post such that you have a sentence which ends in a question mark. Another thing which often trips up those new to the format: good questions will be those you actually care about the answer to. Not *Does anyone know X?* but rather *How do I X?*.

Comment: Thanks Adrian You actually have helped me out a few times now so thank you a ton.  I wrote this late yesterday I will work on that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can't know what process kicked off a scheduled job.** Any scheduled job could be kicked off from the UI or Execute Anonymous, in addition to any classes which might actually do the scheduling.